# Notification action background task not running as expected

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

**UPDATE**

After some comments I changed the `resolveVisita` method to use `URLSession` in the background, but it looks like the background session will only start when the app is in the foreground, here is the updated method that runs when a notification action is tapped:

```
static func resolverVisita(idMensagem: String, resposta: String, liberar: Bool, view: UIViewController?) {

    //let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "url_session_resolve_visita")
    //var backgroundSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration)

    // Set up the URL request
    let todoEndpoint: String = URL_RESPONDE_VISITA

    guard let url = URL(string: todoEndpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "userUUID=\(SessionManager.getUsrUUID())&devUUID=\(devUUID)&msgID=\(idMensagem)&tarefa=\(liberar ? "L" : "B")&resposta=\(resposta)"

    urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "\(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!).responde_visita")

    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    /*
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }*/

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest)
    task.resume()

}
```

The commented out code seem to work sometimes, but it looks like it is not the right way of doing it.

**UPDATE END**

So i have an application that receives notification and it has 2 actions, and upon user response the app should send a response to the server, preferable on the background.

I am facing an issue where whenever an action is tapped, sometimes the `userNotificationCenter` method is not called until the app is opened, and sometimes it does run, but the *Alamofire* server call does not get processed, and then if i open the app some errors are shown in the console regarding the Alamofire call, however if i tap the action then open the app quick enough it works as expected.

[image: Console output errors]

I already enabled *Background Fetch* and *Remote notifications* under the app capabilities on Xcode.

This is how I am creating the actions for the notification:

```
 let liberar = UNTextInputNotificationAction(identifier:"liberar", title:"Liberar",options:[.authenticationRequired],
                                                     textInputButtonTitle: "Liberar",
                                                     textInputPlaceholder: "Resposta")

    let bloquear = UNTextInputNotificationAction(identifier: "bloquear", title: "Bloquear", options: [.destructive],
                                                     textInputButtonTitle: "Bloquear",
                                                     textInputPlaceholder: "Resposta")
```

Here is my `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` protocol implementation:

```
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    let acao = response.actionIdentifier

    //let request = response.notification.request

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    print(acao)

    if acao == "liberar" {
        // Print full message.


        let textResponse = response as! UNTextInputNotificationResponse

        print("Liberando Visita")
        AppConfig.resolverVisita(idMensagem: (userInfo["msgid"] as? String)!, resposta: textResponse.userText, liberar: true, view: nil)
    }

    else if acao == "bloquear" {
        let textResponse = response as! UNTextInputNotificationResponse

        print("Bloqueando Visita")
        AppConfig.resolverVisita(idMensagem: (userInfo["msgid"] as? String)!, resposta: textResponse.userText, liberar: false, view: nil)

        //let newContent = request.content.mutableCopy() as! UNMutableNotificationContent
        //print(textResponse.userText)

    }

    completionHandler()
}}
```

And here is the `resolveVisita` method, it basically just gathers some data and send it via a POST request using Alamofire.

```
static func resolverVisita(idMensagem: String, resposta: String, liberar: Bool, view: UIViewController?) {

    if view != nil {
        showLoading(mensagem: NSLocalizedString("Processando...", comment: ""), view: view!)
    }
    //Parameters to be sent
    let parameters: Parameters=[
        "userUUID":SessionManager.getUsrUUID(),
        "devUUID":devUUID,
        "msgID": idMensagem,
        "resposta": resposta,
        "tarefa": liberar ? "L" : "B"
        ];

    //Sending http post request
    Alamofire.request(URL_RESPONDE_VISITA, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON{
        response in
        //printing response
        print(response)

        //getting the json value from the server
        if let result = response.result.value {

            //converting it as NSDictionary
            let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary

            var mensagem : String = "Solicitacao resolvida com sucesso"

            //displaying the message in label
            if((jsonData["error"] as! Bool)){

                mensagem = jsonData["error_msg"] as! String

                if view == nil {
                    Notificacoes.notificaErroSolicitavao(msgId: idMensagem, errMsg: mensagem)
                }

            }

            if view != nil {
                view?.dismiss(animated: false){
                    showAlert(mensagem: NSLocalizedString(mensagem, comment: ""), view: view!, okMsg: NSLocalizedString("Voltar", comment: ""), segue: "voltarParaLogin")
                }
            }
            else{
                print(mensagem)
            }

        }
    }

}
```

If I just add the `.foreground` option to the actions making the app open once it is selected, the problem is solved however I really think it would not be necessary for the app to be open for this task.

Comment: I'd suggest initiating background `URLSession` request (which is admittedly clumsy with Alamofire) or, at the very least, don't call the notification completion handlers until after the asynchronous `responseJSON` completion handler is called. The typical solution for the latter approach would be to give your method, itself, a completion handler, with you'd call at the end of `responseJSON` closure. And then move the call to the user notification completion handler into that closure.

Comment: @Rob Oh i get it now, when the completion handler is called the background task gets killed, so i have to find a way to call the completion handles on the alamofire response. is that right?

Comment: Yep, that's the idea. And you generally only have a few seconds (30?), which is why you'd use background `URLSession` if the response is unlikely to be received very quickly.

Comment: @Rob I actually don't need the response to be fair, because the server will generate another notification for the response, so I will try with that for now, if i run into problems i might check `URLSession`

Comment: hey mr @Rob so i changed my `resolveVisita` method to use URLSession background instead of alamofire, i created the session, the request did task.resume, but it does not run from the notification! it only works if the app is opened. Do i have to set some special permission in order to start the background session from a notification, or from the lock screen?

Comment: First, are you 100% sure your routine is getting called when you think it is. Second, background requests initiated while the task is running in background have their [`isDiscretionary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1411552-isdiscretionary) turned on by default (and you can't override this). So, are you on wifi? Connected to power? Is it that the request _never_ happens, or just not immediately?

Comment: @Rob oh yes I am, I print a Flag right before the method call just to be sure it is being called, I am on wifi and connected to power, i will update the question with my current code so you can see it better. Cant i just `config.isDiscretionary = true` when setting the session up?

Comment: To quote [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1411552-isdiscretionary), "The session object applies the value of [`isDiscretionary`] only to transfers that your app starts while it is in the foreground. For transfers started while your app is in the background, the system always starts transfers at its discretion—in other words, the system assumes this property is `true` and ignores any value you specified."

Comment: @Rob got it, so i updated the method, please take a look at it, have i done it the right way? Because it works great if i reply the notification with the app in the foreground, but either on the foreground or the lock screen, the method gets called, it even shows on the output that the session had started but the request does not get processed. I also implemented the `application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) ` method on my AppDelegate.

Comment: You didn't specify a delegate for your `URLSession`. I don't know if that will affect the background request. I've always implemented the delegate methods and make sure that `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` saves the completion handler which I then call in [`urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondelegate/1617185-urlsessiondidfinishevents), etc. There's a lot more to background `URLSession` than you've shared with us thus far.

Comment: @Rob I actually have implemented a delegate but im not sure what to do with it, it worked the same way with the delegate, perhaps there is something else left to do on it, also, what completion handler do i have to save? i dont get it, Correct me if im wrong, the flow will go like:
User taps notification -> background Session is created and started -> completion handler is called -> request gets processed -> wakes the app and calls the delegate methods once the request is done. is that right? am i on the right track?

Comment: Yeah, but `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` has its own completion handler which you call when your `URLSession`'s `delegate` is done processing all of the responses. Also, when you instantiate `URLSession`, you have to specify delegate there (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411597-init).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time I've decided to come back to this issue with a fresh mind, and I discovered what I was doing wrong, I Was trying to create my Instance of the `URLSession` in the background from the lock screen, and also creating a new instance of the "same Session", to resolve this, all I had to do was create a static instance of the `URLSession` and use it afterwards whenever I need it.

I created it this way.

```
 static let resolveVisitaSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "br.com.freaccess.resolveVisitaRequest"))
```

And this is the method that gets called upon the selection on a `UNNotificationAction` I use my URLSession in there.

```
static func resolverVisita(idMensagem: String, resposta: String, liberar: Bool) {
    print("Entered resolveVisita method")

    // Set up the URL request
    let todoEndpoint: String = URL_RESPONDE_VISITA

    guard let url = URL(string: todoEndpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "userUUID=\(SessionManager.getUsrUUID())&devUUID=\(devUUID)&msgID=\(idMensagem)&tarefa=\(liberar ? "L" : "B")&resposta=\(resposta)&skipSocket=true"

    urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

    resolveVisitaSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest).resume()
}
```